# SQL: Update max values with min values in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a `priority`. Something like that:

```
id    priority    name
-------------------------------
1     5           SomeFunnyName
2     10          SomeFunnyName1
3     20          SomeFunnyName2
4     30          SomeFunnyName3
5     40          SomeFunnyName4
```

Data with higher priority was proceeded faster. But now i have to change the priority logic. So data with lower priority will proceed faster.

How can i update this table that the data with the highest priority will now have the lowest priority?

Comment: something like set priority = 100 - priority

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: That's a bit confusing. If you want to "change the priority logic", then your data would stay as is and you'd only change the programm, query or whatever that applies the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `MAX` and `MIN` get `priority` and some calculation to make it change the `MAX` and `MIN` priority from the table.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   id int,
   priority int,
   name varchar(50)
);


insert into t values (1,5,'SomeFunnyName');
insert into t values (2,10,'SomeFunnyName1');
insert into t values (3,20,'SomeFunnyName2');
insert into t values (4,30,'SomeFunnyName3');
insert into t values (5,40,'SomeFunnyName4');

UPDATE T 
Set priority = maxVal - priority + minVal
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(priority) maxVal,MIN(priority) minVal 
  FROM T
) t1
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/88bef/1/0)**:

```
| id | priority |           name |
|----|----------|----------------|
|  1 |       40 |  SomeFunnyName |
|  2 |       35 | SomeFunnyName1 |
|  3 |       25 | SomeFunnyName2 |
|  4 |       15 | SomeFunnyName3 |
|  5 |        5 | SomeFunnyName4 |
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine for me :)

Answer (score 2):

When you multiply by minus one it would change the priority, this way you can revert back easily by again multiplying by minus one

```
UPDATE TABLE SET PRIORITY=-1*PRIORITY
```

Comment: I already thought of this :D Thats the easiest way to go. But the Priority should not be negative :/

Comment: Hehehe if that’s the case set (1/Priority)*10^5 cast that as int ;)